# Django Model save method error

Tags: python, django

I am new to python/django and trying to learn by testing an app but can't figure out what's wrong with the save method used in the view [resp.save()]. The save method seems to be not working and it leads to 500 error. Without this save line the error would be "null" in the response. Tried to overwrite the save method in the model following suggestions found online, but couldn't get it the work either.

Data validation passed with no problems before the save method. Any suggestions?

models.py

```
class Response(models.Model):
    dt_start = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    dt_end = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, related_name="responses")
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Survey=%s, %s' % (self.survey.title, self.dt_end.strftime('%d %B'))
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['dt_end']
```

views.py

```
def create_response(request):
    if request.POST:
        resp = Response()
        resp.dt_start = request.session.get('dt_start')
        resp.dt_end = datetime.now()
        resp.survey = Survey.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get("surveyID")))
        #My tests show the line below causes the error
        resp.save()
        dict = {"responseID": resp.id}
        return JsonResponse(dict)
    return error_jump(request)
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to tell us what the error is.

Comment: Sorry, just added. It doesn't provide more information than that.

Comment: Set DEBUG to true and report the actual error.

Comment: It's been on DEBUG mode [DEBUG = True] but it doesn't provide any feedback (i.e., no response) from the browser, and I only see this one line in the prompt window:".. HTTP/1.1" 500 14381

Comment: Well, since you're using a JsonResponse presumably this is an Ajax request. The full error message will be visible in the browser dev tools. Really, we can't help until we see it.

Comment: You won't see the error in browser. Check the console where you are running the server ( for unix - Terminal, for windows, Command Prompt), It will give you a log along with a stack trace.

Comment: is `dt_start` a valid date object? Its pretty much guess work at what the error could be without more information

Comment: Thank you, guys. I followed Daniel's suggestion to use the browser dev tools and found some errors with jQuery. I will try to solve the errors in the messages and report back.

Comment: This is not a python/django problem. There were some errors in jQuery codes. Thank you for helping me find the source of error!